# ST_Distance column empty in self join query

Tags: postgresql, distance, st-distance

[image]

So I am working on an assignment with a database of GIS club members that includes the following columns: id, firstname, lastname, postalcode, and geom. I am querying to find which member is closest to the member with the ID 14. I'm not sure why, but with the query I have (in the attached image), the ST_Distance column keeps coming up with all NULL values. Does anyone have an idea what might be the issue?

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.firstname,
    t1.lastname,
    ST_Distance(t1.geom::geography, t2.geom::geography)
    
FROM members as t1, members as t2
WHERE t1.id <> t2.id AND t2.id = 14
ORDER BY ST_Distance(t1.geom::geography, t2.geom::geography) ASC
```

Comment: The usual reason for a NULL distance is that one of the two geometries is NULL.  Note that placing table lists in the FROM is very old-school (SQL-89, in fact) and JOIN is very much the modern (and preferred) way to join tables.

Comment: ST_DISTANCE +ST_DWITHIN +JOIN & Geography example https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213872/276

Comment: Your query works for me with a simple shapefile (states.shp from the GeoServer demo data). Test the `ST_Distance(t1.geom::geography, t2.geom::geography)` with two selected features and make sure that is works. IMHO the old school SQL is easier to read and is ok if not preferred in gis.stackexchange questions :).

Comment: when in doubt add the two geometries to the select to see what their values are